# windows-7 outlook2010 .pst file merge?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

Through a process of moving between three computers I've ended up with two .pst files for my emails. One is for the older ones and one is the newer (currently the default). I can change the default to read the old one, but does anyone know a neat way of merging the two files. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing, you can import the PSTs into an existing PST thus combining them into a super PST with which you can take over the world*

I am assuming you are using Outlook outside of Exchange?

Do the following:

File > Open > Import > Import from another file > Outlook data file (PST) > Browse for your PST and decide what to do with the duplicates > Done.

*may or may not be true

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the world domination laugh. D

Answer (score -1):

The manual solution indeed came up with same issues when i performed it. I had around 146 PST files for our **Support** Email Id, that were supposed to be merged. Our technical team performed a deep and extensive search and got a solution through this Article. I am specially asked by my Team Manager to share the link with people who are finding issues merging Their PST files.
[How To Combine Multiple PST files](http://wordpress.semnaitik.com/2013/06/19/merge-pst-files/)

Comment: sure -- Will keep it in mind in future